# Unexpected output after running this little bit strange c code. Can anyone explain how this happened?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

I am trying to understand how this code works,

```
int main () {
 int m, k;
 m = (k=5)+(k=8)+(k=9)+(k=7);
 printf("m=%d\n",m);
 printf("k=%d\n",k);
}
```

The output:
m=32
k=7

I have no idea how is the value of m become 32.
I hope someone can help me to understand how this code works and how the outputs end up like this

Comment: C or C++? The answers will be different.

Comment: Also in case of C++ the language version matters.

Comment: @Lundin `+` operands are unsequenced in all versions.

Comment: warnings are your friend:
"warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'k'"

Comment: Anyway, I'll simply down vote and close vote as unclear until the question is edited into shape with the incorrect language tags removed. Feel free to @Lundin me when it is fixed and I'll retract them. I've lost all patience with these cross-tagging questions. Kindly read the tag usage wiki of a tag before using it. Kindly make an effort to know what programming language you are coding in before you start coding.

Comment: This code is ugly, don't write in this way.

Comment: @molbdnilo False. + is sequenced from let to right (left associativity), but evaluation order of subexpressions is undefined.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Associativity is not sequencing. Per C 2018 5.1.2.3 3, sequencing is defined as ordering on evaluations of expressions. It is nonsensical to say something is sequenced but evaluation order of subexpressions is undefined: Sequencing is specifying evaluation order.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i used c here

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1.9 Program execution note 9 say exactly the converse a+b+c is evaluated as (a+b)+c. What is undefined is the order with which a, b and c subexpressions are evaluated. If not associativity would means nothing at all.

Comment: if you run  (k=5) the out put is  5. so m = (k=5)+(k=8)+(k=9)+(k=7) means m=5+8+9+7 that is 32 ; and in the last value of k is 7.

Comment: Careless talk. Prefer to say that `a + b + c` is *grouped* as `(a + b) + c`. You can't say what is *evaluated* when, since there are no sequencing points in the expression.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Neither the C standard nor the C++ standard has a clause 1.9. I have no idea what your “1.9 Program execution note 9” refers to. `a+b+c` is **structured** as `(a+b)+c`. That does not tell us how it is evaluated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I quite like that term *structured*. I wonder where I get my term *group* from? By the way, I second all your comments.

Comment: *Can anyone explain how this happened?*  The **C** programming language is not a nanny language.  It presumes that the programmer knows what they're doing, and doesn't prevent them from doing bad things like buffer overruns or multiple unsequenced modifications or egregious cavalier casting.

Comment: @EricPostpischil a = a + 32760 + b + 5;
the expression statement behaves exactly the same as
      a = (((a + 32760) + b) + 5);
due to the associativity and precedence of these operators. Thus, the result of the sum (a + 32760) is next added to b, and that result is then added to 5 which results in the value assigned to a. On a machine in which overflows produce an exception and in which the range of values representable by an int is [-32768,+32767], the implementation cannot rewrite this expression as
      a = ((a + b) + 32765);

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: no, no, no. *structuring* (*grouping*?) are different things entirely from the algebraic concept of what gets added to when.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: So? The **value** computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. But the **side effects** are not. Neither `a + b + c` nor `(a + b) + c)` imposes any ordering on the side effects of the operands. `+` is not “sequenced” to impose any ordering on these side effects. The side effects in `a`, `b`, and `c` may be performed in any order or even intermingled, and those are the computations that are at issue in this question.

Comment: @Eljay In all fairness, the standard could have mandated a certain order of evaluation but it didn't. Supposedly it's an old argument of compiler/executable speed vs language usefulness. C chose to be less useful in favour of performance. Rational language designers could also simply have made it a constraint violation to write multiple side effects on the same variable in the same expression. This would have made the language safer and cost nothing. But C wasn't rationally designed.

Comment: @Bathsheba Uh? C17 5.1.2.3 Note 15 Example 6. Order is explicitly stated, otherwise computation may not lead to consistent results (intermadiate trap representations). What I missed?

Comment: @EricPostpischil intermediate results may lead to wrong computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified explanation:

When you use `k=...` multiple times in the same expression, all assignments to that same variable are so-called "unsequenced side-effects". Simply put, it means that C doesn't specify which operand of `+` to evaluate/execute first nor does it specify the order in which the assignments will get carried out.

So the compiler has no way of knowing which `k` to evaluate/assign to first and therefore gets all confused. This is so-called "undefined behavior", anything can happen.

You have to solve this by splitting the expression up in several, each separated by a semicolon, which acts as a "sequence point", meaning all prior evaluations need to be done at the point where the `;` is encounterd. Example:

```
k=5;
k+=8;
k+=9;
m = k + 7;
```

Detailed explanation with standard references here: [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384)

Comment: This is the only *sensible* answer so far.

Comment: There is no `+=` in the question, and `k +=` does not express any intent evident in the question. Code aligned with the apparent intent would be `m = k = 5; m += k = 8; m += k = 9; m += k = 7;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is one way out of many to re-write the original code in a well-defined manner.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you, Now i understood the flaw's in code. it was my first time submitting a question in stack overflow, so i forgot to pay attention to the tags i used at fisrt.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior. Your compiler warn about this

> warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'k' [-Wunsequenced]

You can learn more about this here:

- [A Guide to Undefined Behavior](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)
- [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)
- [What are “sequence points” and how do they affect undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/what-are-sequence-points-and-how-do-they-affect-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @smith shah Thank you!, i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the program is *undefined*.

There are multiple unsequenced writes on `k` in the expression

```
(k = 5) + (k = 8) + (k = 9) + (k = 7)
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm starting to think this too. I'll ask the community.

Comment: `...5, k)` isn't sequenced with `+ (k = ...)` so it is still UB. If you want to use comma as  abominable "sequence point padding", it will have to be `(0,k=5) + (0,k=8)` or some such.

Comment: subexpressions evaluation is not ordered, adding a sequence point in subexpressions doesn't change the "global" behaviour of subexpressions evaluation order.

Comment: @EricPostpischil   Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619477/is-a-0-a-a-1-a-undefined-behaviour

Comment: (comments above relate to a previous version of this answer, hopefully to be cleared up with my question).

Comment: @Lundin, Above my pay grade - I've asked the community.