# Is (a = 0, a) + (a =1, a) undefined behaviour for int a?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b = (a = 0, a) + (a = 1, a);
}
```

defined? Without the `, a` in each term, the program behaviour is clearly undefined due to multiple unsequenced writes to `a`, but don't the `,` introduce adequate sequencing points?

Comment: @Answerers, feel free to remove the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: No; the parentheses isolate the sequences. (And the sequences you've got do nothing but reinforce the defined behavior portion).

Comment: We agree that such code should never be written, even if it is defined behaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well especially if the behaviour is undefined ;-)

Comment: The comma operator has exactly 3 uses: - icky function-like macros that return a value - sequence point language lawyer debates - code golf.

Comment: @Bathsheba In this case I would say that it's equally bad if the behavior is defined or not. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it isn't well-defined. Suppose we replace all sequence point in your code with pseudo code "SQ":

```
SQ
int b = (a = 0 SQ a) + (a = 1 SQ a) SQ
```

Then we have `SQ a) + (a = 1 SQ` where two accesses and one side effect happens to `a` between sequence points, so it is still undefined behavior.

We could write well-defined (but of course very bad and fishy) code like this:

```
(0, a = 0) + (0, a = 1)
```

The order of evaluation of the + operands is still unspecified, but the compiler must evaluate either parenthesis before moving on to the next. So there's always a comma operator sequence point between the side-effects/access of `a`.